# Perform different function if year is certain value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have the following line of code which sets the content or a label to a date.

```
cell.birthdayLabel.text = [[GlobalBirthdaysEditor instance] getFormattedDateString:[birthday getDate]];
```

I need to find out in the year is equal to 1604 and, if so, not show it.

How can I pull the year from this object and then alter the result so it just prints month and day?

The code I have so far is:

```
NSString *dateString = [[GlobalBirthdaysEditor instance] getFormattedDateString:[birthday getDate]];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger year = [components year];

if (year == 1604)
{
    cell.birthdayLabel.text = yearStr; //SHOULD OUTPUT JUST MONTH AND DAY
} else {
    cell.birthdayLabel.text = [[GlobalBirthdaysEditor instance] getFormattedDateString:[birthday getDate]];
}
```

But this does   not work. It runs, but the date is always the second one. Why is this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you converting the year to a string? Just do `if (year == 1604)`.

Comment: Was just doing that so I could use it elsewhere, forgot to change it back. I'll edit code. But, changed it to this and there's still no effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues. It should be:

```
NSDate *date = [birthday getDate];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger year = [components year];

if (year == 1604) {
    // Adjust this as needed
    NSString *yearStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", year];
    cell.birthdayLabel.text = yearStr; //SHOULD OUTPUT JUST MONTH AND DAY
} else {
    NSString *dateString = [[GlobalBirthdaysEditor instance] getFormattedDateString:date];
    cell.birthdayLabel.text = dateString;
}
```

The main issue is that you are passing a new date to the `components:` method call instead of passing your actual date.

There is no reason to go back and forth between `NSString` and `NSDate`. Since you already have access to the `NSDate`, use it.